# Custom Hub Control for WP8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, uigesturerecognizer

I have some problems with understanding how [Hub](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.hub.aspx) Control is built.
The main idea of what I want to understand is how to build a custom control which allows to perform some gestures and which will not block controls inside.

Using `Hub` control I can press a `Button` and see its callback (color and size changing) and then move pointer left slide the `Hub` control.

Sorry about this such a stupid question but I don't have enough experience to find any  responses by myself. Thanks in advance about any advice.

Comment: @Will, thanks for replay. Should you recommend appropriate tool for making this?

Comment: You can use your favorite search engine to look for .net disassemblers. There are many, try a few and find out which one suits you the best.

Comment: @Will, I have used `JustDecompile`, but there were just external calls and nothing more. The same situation like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12843830/decompiled-winmd-file-contains-nothing-but-external-calls). May be you can advice me another tool?

Comment: You didn't look at the template for the control. That's where the fun is. Your tool will be your guide.

Comment: @Will, it was the first what I've done. The main tricks are hided in code-behind. Templates of `Hub` and `HubSection` are pretty simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem was associated with using of `GestureRecognizer`. 
I have fixed my problem refusing to use `GestureRecognizer` and starting to use Manipulation Events over the main container.

The simplified template code:

```
<Style TargetType="my:CustomHub">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="my:CustomHub">
                <Grid x:Name="RootGrid">
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="MainPresenter" 
                                      Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Control's code-behind:

```
public sealed class CustomHub
{
    public FrameworkElement Container { get; set; }

    public MainView()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void InitGestureInteraction()
    {
        this.Container = (FrameworkElement)GetTemplateChild("RootGrid");
        this.Container.ManipulationMode = ManipulationModes.TranslateX | ManipulationModes.TranslateRailsX;

        this.Container.ManipulationStarted += (s, e) =>
        {
        };

        this.Container.ManipulationDelta += (s, e) =>
        {
            var x = e.Cumulative.Translation.X;
            // implementation of moving
        };

        this.Container.ManipulationCompleted += (s, e) =>
        {
            var x = e.Cumulative.Translation.X;
            // implementation of moving
        };
    }
}
```